# Fedex - Shipping Label generation not working

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, fedex, wsdl

I cannot identify the reason that cause Fedex Shipping Label not working on Magento (1.7.0.2).
Everytime I try to generate a new label, I got this message:

> An error occurred while creating shipping label.

`Exception.log` shows:

```
SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Fault in app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php:1470
```

The exception is triggered by this call in `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex` (1470)

```
$response = $client->processShipment($requestClient);
```

How can I go further ? Is it an issue on FedEx server side ?

Comment: is it solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FedEx have changed their Web-Service URL.
If you're on 1.7.0.2 copy the file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php and make the following changes to it:

Line 135

```
$client->__setLocation($this->getConfigFlag('sandbox_mode')
    ? 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate'
    : 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate'
);
```

Change to:

```
$client->__setLocation($this->getConfigFlag('sandbox_mode')
    ? 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services'
    : 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services'
);
```

Comment: I'm getting "Authentication Required" even though I plugged in Production keys/passwords. Quotes and Tracking are working but label creation not.

Comment: @KalvinKlien : is it solve your problem

Comment: https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services, https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services this URL also returns empty page.....